# Code::Blocks, C, view struct while debugging

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks, doubly-linked-list

So, I am doing a project where I need to use three doubly linked lists.
Being fairly new to this I am worried about my pointers and memoryleaks so I would like to visually see my lists. Looking for pretty much the same thing where you can watch the contents of an array, not just the adress it starts at.

This will be critical when I later continue with the project to make these three lists into the base for a rtos with passing around messages and tasks and timers.

I recall this was for example possible in IAR Embedded Workbench, and was greatly helpful.

Is there a way I can do that in Code::Blocks?

Picture one is what it looks like at the moment, not very helpful.

Here in picture two we can see the entire struct and follow its pointers as well as memory to easily spot for example endless loops and easier to understand how the struct looks.
[image: This is what I got now, not helpful to spot bad linking]
[image]

Comment: I actually have no idea, but maybe the following helps? http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugger_scripts

Comment: Cheers, that looks interesting but dont think it do what I was hoping for. I have a screen shot from school, will include it in the first post of what I want.

Comment: Then maybe its time to look at GDB Python pretty printers... as far as I understand the GDB output will be used by CodeBlocks to display the debugging window contents. https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/make-debugging-easier-with-custom-pretty-printers/ https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html Dunno if I'm actually helping by throwing some random things in. Maybe you already found those yourself :)